# Alterar create.objectURL para HTMLMediaElement.srcObject

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mvc

Ao adicionar a classe createObjectURL, ele está acusando o erro reprovado em alguns navegadores, depois das pesquisas, verifiquei que posso usar o HTMLMediaElement. Mas como posso incluí-lo no meu projeto?

```
export class CameraController {

    constructor(videoEl){

        this._videoEl = videoEl;

        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
            video:true
        }).then(stream=>{

        this._stream = stream;
        this._videoEl.src = URL.createObjectURL(stream);
        this.videoEl.play(); 

        }).catch(err=>{
            console.error(err);
        });
    }

    stop(){

        this._stream.getTracks().forEach(track=>{
            track.stop();
        });
    }

    takePicture(mimeType = 'image/png'){

        let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

        canvas.setAttribute('height', this._videoEl.videoHeight);
        canvas.setAttribute('width', this._videoEl.videoWidth);

        let context = canvas.getContext('2d');

        context.drawImage(this._videoEl, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        return canvas.toDataURL(mimeType);

    }
}
```

Comment: Qual o erro????

Comment: TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided.
    at CameraController.navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia.then.stream (bundle.js:9763)

Comment: Verifiquei que é o createObjectURL que já está desabilitado no chrome pois no opera ainda funciona mas recebe uma mensagem de aviso que está depreciado o código.

Comment: não seria `window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);`?

Comment: você também pode tentar `this._videoEl.srcObject = stream;`